# Iterate in div for all child div and get their name

Tags: jquery

basically i want to calculate all child div height excluding one
here is my code

```
            var allChildDivHeight = 0;
            this.children().each(function (e) {
                //alert($(this).attr('id'));
                if ($(this).attr('id') != 'BlindBox') {
                    allChildDivHeight = allChildDivHeight + $(this).outerHeight();
                }
            });
```

i want to calculate all child div height excluding one child div name "BlindBox". my code is not working. what is the prob

Comment: And what HTML are you working with? Also `this` is a DOM node, not a jQuery object (use `$(this)`).

Comment: You can't leverage a jQuery method against a non jQuery object. `this` needs to be `$(this)`. [here's the working fiddle changing only what I said.](http://jsfiddle.net/fqGYk/)

Comment: anyone can check this issue. here is url http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12763289/div-appear-with-blind-effect-issue-jquery i post it few days back but still no body answer for this question. please read my question and tell me what is the problem in the code. thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Depending on the context in which this is executed if this is not a jQuery object you need to select it. Also limit the children to only div-s:

```
        var allChildDivHeight = 0;
        $(this).children('div').each(function (e) {
            //alert($(this).attr('id'));
            if ($(this).attr('id') != 'BlindBox') {
                allChildDivHeight = allChildDivHeight + $(this).outerHeight();
            }
        });
```

Comment: anyone can check this issue. here is url http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12763289/div-appear-with-blind-effect-issue-jquery i post it few days back but still no body answer for this question. please read my question and tell me what is the problem in the code. thanks

Answer (score 0):

Aside from the suggestions made in the comments, the code looks sound. Have you checked to make sure that you are calling this from the document ready event? If you are not, then the elements would have not been rendered at the time you are making the call.

Here's an example:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    // Your code here
});
```

However, the short-hand form of this is the preferred way of doing it:

```
$(function() {
    // Your code here
});
```

Comment: anyone can check this issue. here is url http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12763289/div-appear-with-blind-effect-issue-jquery i post it few days back but still no body answer for this question. please read my question and tell me what is the problem in the code. thanks

Answer (score 0):

Try below, if you want to compute all `div` heights in the page except "BlindBox""

```
    var allChildDivHeight = 0;
    $('div').each(function (e) {
        if ($(this).attr('id') != 'BlindBox') {
            allChildDivHeight = allChildDivHeight + $(this).outerHeight();
        }
    });
```

Comment: anyone can check this issue. here is url stackoverflow.com/questions/12763289/… i post it few days back but still no body answer for this question. please read my question and tell me what is the problem in the code. thanks